# howto create api service

Tags: php

I have an application which handles some data. Now i want to make the data available throughout a php api (something like zend_gdata for google) so my application's users can handle the data from my application in their own applications on an other host.

Is this possible? Can someone hook me up whith some literature or ideas?

Comment: There are lots of other questions with information about this:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create+an+api+php

Comment: This one is my favorite:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728/how-should-i-build-a-good-web-api

Answer (score 1):

This has been written about on numerous occasions.  Here is some reading material:

- [Creating a REST API with PHP](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)
- [How to Add an API to your Web Service](http://particletree.com/features/how-to-add-an-api-to-your-web-service/)